# Return delegate function based on type

Tags: c#

Having the following code:

```
public delegate Task<bool> CreateObject<TU>
      (TU obj, object parameters, Expression<Func<TU, object[]>> includes = null);

// This Version compile
public CreateObject<Dummy> Example1(Type listOfType)
{
    CreateObject<Dummy> c = DummyRepository.InsertAsync;
    return c;
}

// This Version do NOT compile    
public CreateObject<TU> Example2<TU>(Type listOfType)
{
    if (listOfType == typeof(Dummy)) return DummyRepository.InsertAsync;
    if (listOfType == typeof(DummyName)) return DummyNameRepository.InsertAsync;
    if (listOfType == typeof(DummyEntry)) return DummyEntryRepository.InsertAsync;
    return null;
}
// This Version do NOT compile    
public CreateObject<TU> Example3<TU>()
{
    if (typeof(TU) == typeof(Dummy)) return DummyRepository.InsertAsync;
    if (typeof(TU) == typeof(DummyName)) return DummyNameRepository.InsertAsync;
    if (typeof(TU) == typeof(DummyEntry)) return DummyEntryRepository.InsertAsync;
    return null;
}
```

I am trying to return a method (all share signature based on T), however, I am having problems writing this code, anyone knows how to do it?

The solution I need, must be based on the Example2, where I use the Type `listOfType`, and for that reason I would like to avoid calling the method whith the generic TU...

**Update: #1**

```
if (listOfType == typeof(Dummy)) return (CreateObject<object>)(object)(CreateObject<Dummy>)DummyRepository.InsertAsync;
```

This line, compiles, but does not work...

Any other options? What kind of other design pattern or solution do I have?

Comment: The versions that dont compile aren't creating the delegates... The first one will because you are explicitly creating a delegate.

Comment: You cannot apply runtime logic on generic types.

Comment: @Ankur Yes, I get that, but what other solution do I have to implement the purpose I want?

Comment: You can use interfaces i.e Create an interface, implement the interface for all the 3 cases and use the interface as the return type of the Example2 function

Comment: A rule of thumb: If your generic type has to test the type of its generic parameters, then (for me at least) it's a strong indicator that generics is being misused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working solution:

```
public dynamic Example7(Type listOfType)
{
    CreateObject<Dummy> a1 = DummyRepository.InsertAsync;
    if (listOfType == typeof(Dummy)) return (CreateObject<Dummy>)DummyRepository.InsertAsync;
    if (listOfType == typeof(DummyName)) return (CreateObject<DummyName>)DummyNameRepository.InsertAsync;
    if (listOfType == typeof(DummyEntry)) return (CreateObject<DummyEntry>)DummyEntryRepository.InsertAsync;
    return null;
}
```

Then, on the solution explorer window, right click to References, select Add Reference, go to .NET tab, find and add Microsoft.CSharp.

The "consumer class" will have something like:

```
var rep = uow.Example7(listOfType);
foreach (var t in list as dynamic)
{
   .....
   var res = await rep(t, null, null);
```

And it is working.... I still did not make any performance/speed tests, but at least the code is doing what I was looking for.....